# Flask - how to read the raw input from non-HTTP request?

Tags: python, http, flask

I have a device that sends commands to a webserver. I've redirected those commands to my own server, with the goal of use the device to run another part of my system. In short, the device sends commands, I intercept them and use them.

The commands are sent to my server,but are not valid HTTP requests. I'm trying to use flask to read them with python, because I'd like to have these commands go straight into another web app.

Note that I can't change how the commands are sent.

Using sockets, I can read the data. For instance, here is a version of the data sent via socket (data is meaningless, just for illustration):

`b'#123456#A'`

In constrast, as HTTP message looks like this:

`b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 123.123.123.123:12345\r\nRequest info here'`

I know how to filter these (they always start with a #). Can I hook flask to let me handle these request differently, *before they are parsed as HTTP requests*?

Update: The code I used to read the requests, in case it provides context:

```
import socket 

host = '' 
port = 5000
backlog = 5 
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog) 
while 1: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size)
    print("Request:")
    print(data)
    print("\n\n")
    if data: 
        client.send(data) 
    client.close()
```

Comment: Here is the code that I used to get the data from the socket:

import socket 

host = '' 
port = 5000
backlog = 5 
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog) 
while 1: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size)
    print("Request:")
    print(data)
    print("\n\n")
    if data: 
        client.send(data) 
    client.close()

Comment: Please if you want to include any code then update your question instead